# Using an "if" to delete an item from a list gives a syntax error

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm trying to write some code that has a list of enemies, then deletes the enemy if they go off screen. the code is as follows:

```
for enemy in enemies:
    index = 0
    enemy[0] += 2
    if enemy[1] >= 270:
        enemy[2] = -2
    else:
        enemy[2] = enemy[2] + 0.01
    enemy[1] = enemy[1] + enemy[2]
    screen.blit(enemyImg, (enemy[0],enemy[1])

    if enemy[0] > 470:
        enemies.remove(index)
    index += 1
```

I'm using a for loop which is why it has "enemy" as a a list but it's deleting the item in the list "enemies"

The information stored in "enemy" is a list that has the x-value (index 0), y-value (index 1), and the y velocity (index 2). The enemies don't have a x velocity since they move at a constant rate to the right.

The error says that there is invalid syntax (that's literally all it says), but I don't see a problem. Maybe I'm just missing something stupid, but I'm not sure. Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: Show the full error traceback

Comment: and also show more code

Comment: probably missing parenthesis somewhere above the "if". typo

Comment: Include the for loop you mention, also the full error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would remove items from a list called enemies when that item is larger than 470.

```
enemies = [2,500,1,2,4000]
for enemy in enemies:
    if enemy > 470:
        enemies.remove(enemy)
```

If you wanted to do this using list comprehension (more condensed code), you could do this:

```
[enemies.remove(enemy) for enemy in enemies if enemy > 470]
```

Comment: `list.remove` is O(n), making the whole operation more almost O(n^2). It could be done in O(1), making the whole operation O(n). List comprehension is the better way to do it, not your first code block

Comment: Mutating an iterable while you're iterating over it is a bad idea. Run the code with this list `[600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]`. The result will be `[700, 900]`. You can iterate over a slice copy to prevent this or use a list comprehension as @nog642 suggested. Also, list comprehensions shouldn't be used for side effects like mutating another list but to create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter an existing list, it's usually better to create a new one and then assign it to the old variable name. You can do this in one line with a [list comprehension](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/):

```
>>> enemies = [600, 50, 700, 95, 800, 900, 1000]
>>> enemies = [x for x in enemies if x < 470]
>>> enemies
[50, 95]
```

Here's an example that probably resembles your code more closely.

```
>>> enemies = [[50, 120, 5], [500, 90, 5], [600, 160, 5], [70, 20, 5]]
>>> enemies = [enemy for enemy in enemies if enemy[0] < 470]
>>> enemies
[[50, 120, 5], [70, 20, 5]]
```